# Which Dependency Injection frameworks are best for ASP.NET MVC 4?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, dependency-injection, inversion-of-control

I am new to Dependency Injection and working on a project developed in ASP.NET MVC 4. So, I came across with the use of Dependency Injection and curious to know which frameworks have good performance and support for ASP.NET MVC 4.

I am creating a multi-layered architecture using Repository Pattern, UnitOfWork, and Service Layer as a business logic. So, I want dependency injection. I don't have much idea as of now on other requirements, I think it should support MVC 4.

Proper Question : Which Dependency injection frameworks are best for ASP.NET MVC 4? I came across Simple Injector but somewhere it was mentioned that it does not support MVC 4.

Comment: Do you have any other requirements, other than that it should support ASP.NET MVC 4? Clarity on this helps in suggesting an appropriate DI framework, as in many cases no one framework is "best".

Comment: I am creating a multi-layered architecture using Repository Pattern, UnitOfWork, and Service Layer as a business logic. So, I want dependency injection. I don't have much idea as of now I think it should support MVC 4.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Simple Injector](http://simpleinjector.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=MVC%20Integration) definitely supports MVC4. They got a quick start package for MVC. It states that it's for MVC3, but it works just fine for MVC4 too.

I used it recently in a project and it works like a charm, I like it for it's simplicity. Don't expect tons of conventions and hidden configurations, you just have to create a container and register the dependencies explicitly.

Comment: Is their any good documentation of Simple Injector?

Comment: @ShivamChopra yeah, for sure. The link I provider contains a basic example of registering services. [Here](http://simpleinjector.codeplex.com/documentation) you can find all the documentation.

Answer (score 2):

What would be the best framework is a matter of what requirements you and/or your project have.

Ninject supports MVC4. I'm using this in a couple of projects, both MVC and WebAPI.

[Ninject website](http://www.ninject.org/)

[Using Ninject with WebAPI](http://www.peterprovost.org/blog/2012/06/19/adding-ninject-to-web-api/)

[Using Ninject with MVC4](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/412383/Dependency-Injection-in-asp-net-mvc4-and-webapi-us)

Google has a lot of hits for this.